# Simple Image Swap Function

Tags: javascript, image, getelementbyid

I can't figure out why the first function works and the second does not.

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div>
   <img id="mainImg" src="images/image1.jpg">
   </div>
   <button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Swap Image</button>
</body> 

function changeImage() {
     document.getElementById("mainImg").src="images/image2.jpg";     
}

function changeImage() {
    if (document.getElementById("mainImg").src=="images/image1.jpg") {
            document.getElementById("mainImg").src="images/image2.jpg";
    }       
}
```

Comment: it should work ;) See the console. He is my friend and I'll tell him to show what error your code is throwing

Comment: so what is the error in console

Comment: Fixed with better solution:
    var pix = 1;
    function switchImg() {
        pix += 1;
        if (pix < 4) {
            document.getElementById("mainImg").src="images/img" +           pix + ".jpg";
                }
                else {
             document.getElementById("mainImg").src="images/img1.jpg";
                pix = 1;
                }
}